# Finding user process for Windows kernel API call

Tags: windows

I've set breakpoints on some Windows kernel functions using WinDBG. When the breakpoints are hit, I can query information about the invoking user-mode process using the `!process` or `!peb` commands.

How are these commands implemented? How can I find the relevant memory structures and "manually" trace back to the user-mode caller when one of my BPs hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

currentprocess KPROCESS offset is returned by

```
IDebugSystemObjects::GetCurrentProcessDataOffset
```

peb is returned by

```
IDebugSystemObjects::GetCurrentProcessPeb method
```

both are implemented in dbgeng

you can set process specific breakpoints so that the kernel api will break only in the correct process context

```
bp /p [eprocess] {kernel api}
```

to look at the stack use `kb` when the breakpoint is hit

windbg comes with sample src code that shows various forms of implementation 
right from the very old wdbgext extensions to the latest engextcpp extension

a basic implementation is simple and straightforward 
Call DebugCreate() to obtain a IDebugClient Interface 
Query the Other Interfaces from this Client Interface and call the methods

to find a series of articles that show how to use the dbgeng functions 
explore here 
http://www.woodmann.com/forum/entry.php?246-A-Simple-Dbgeng-Based-User-Mode-Debugger

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to any implementation details of the mentioned debug methods?

Comment: added some details and a link explore